# Linux - Easy way to scroll in C++

Tags: c++, linux, scroll

In my C++ program on linux, I am trying to do a scroll on the current windows. I am searching a easy way to do this and Xorg scares me (So much stuff!). I have read on xdotools and things like that, but I'm not sure... Is there somewhere a nice library that manages X?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the internal mechanism of scrolling is consistent across different UI toolkits, so your best bet is simulating a mouse scrollwheel action.

Comment: why don't you use some high-level desktop management system like gnome or kde? I'm sure sure whatever GUI editor you'll use then, will have an intuitive scrolling functionality.

Comment: @ylabidi I think you're missing the point. He wants to write a program that can manipulate windows of other programs by scrolling inside them.

Comment: It is not easily possible in a fail-proof way. Did you consider either using Qt in your application (and make it a GUI application) or using `ncurses` in your application (and making it a console application). Or perhaps sending some [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) ...